# Condition within html tags using Razor (mvc3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, conditional-statements

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
<input type="checkbox" ('@ViewData["Mailing"]'!= null ? @checked) />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
<input type="checkbox" @(ViewData["Mailing"] != null ? @checked : "") />
```

but it is not something that you should want to do especially when you have strongly typed helpers at your disposal that already take care for this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Mailing)
```

Shorter, strongly typed, no ViewData, no spaghetti.